# Can I set up a unit test to run many times and return the percentage success?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing, and have been scouring the web, trying to figure out how to further automate my unit tests.  I am building a registration scheme, and what I want to do is test it with a variety of hard drive serial numbers, app numbers, etc.  I want to generate a registration key and then check it to make sure it decodes properly.  I am looking to automate running the test (with the integrated Visual Studio Test Environment) with a variety of inputs, and after thousands of runs, find out what % of the tests were successful and unsuccessful.  Is this possible?  Below is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GeneratingValidKeyTest()
    {
        int numReadDevices;
        string appNum = "123";
        string hddSerial = "1234567890";
        string numDevices = "12";
        string regNumber = Registration.GenerateKey(appNum, numDevices, hddSerial);
        Assert.IsTrue(Registration.CheckKey(regNumber, appNum, out numReadDevices, hddSerial), "Generated key does not pass check.");
        Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(numDevices), numReadDevices,"Number of registered devices does not match requested number");
    }
```

Comment: `NUnit` provides convinent approach, take a look at this article http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5

Comment: There may be value to such a test, but it's not a unit test. For automated unit tests, you want code that either passes or fails - and given the same inputs, always returns the same results. You may want to check out https://github.com/fsharp/FsCheck - but that's more "does my code satisfy these properties for many inputs?"

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I find very little value in the "throw lots of random data at the method and make sure it all works" approach.

If you give 500 different serial numbers to the method and they all work, that's fine. But what specific scenarios are they testing in your code? If you can't answer that question, you're probably duplicating test scenarios, and more importantly, **missing** test scenarios.

Instead of throwing test cases at the wall and seeing what sticks, analyze your code and identify the critical success and failure criteria and craft tests that exercise those criteria. This has a side benefit of making your tests more verbose and giving your team members a better idea of what the code is supposed to be doing just by reading the test names. Instead of `GeneratingValidKeyTest`, your tests should be named such that they describe *what* they're testing.

As an example, let's say you're building a calculator. With your approach, you'd toss a ton of addition cases at it -- 1+1, 1+3, 5+30, etc. But it's likely that you'd miss 1+`Int32.MaxValue`. Or maybe you wouldn't try adding negative numbers. Or testing what happens if the input isn't a valid number. And so on.

Good tests force you to think through all of these types of scenarios as you're writing them.

Comment: Unless, of course, you are testing for specific bounds of random values generated by code.  For instance, I have a method that returns a number of x length.  It can also take a boolean value that allows or disallows the first digit to be zero.  I want to make sure it always works.  Since the method generates the number itself, testing the method hundreds of times is probably the best way to be confident that it's working as intended (not allowing a leading zero when it shouldn't).

Answer (score 2):

If you use NUnit you can set up a series of ValueSources to feed into your method.

If you have a separate value source for appNum, hddSerial and numDevices, you'll get appNum * hddSerial * numDevices number of tests.

You shouldn't be aiming to find a percentage of tests pass, though.  The purpose of unit testing is to ensure that all test scenarios pass.

To take Max's example and make it ValueSources:

```
[Test]
public void DivideTest([ValueSource("AppNums")]string appNum, [ValueSource("Serials")]string hddSerial, [ValueSource("NumDevices")]string numDevices)
{
    string regNumber = Registration.GenerateKey(appNum, numDevices, hddSerial);
    Assert.IsTrue(Registration.CheckKey(regNumber, appNum, out numReadDevices, hddSerial), "Generated key does not pass check.");
    Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(numDevices), numReadDevices,"Number of registered devices does not match requested number");
}

static object[] AppNums =
{
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
};

static object[] Serials =
{
    "EXAMPLE", "ANOTHER", "AND AGAIN"
};

static object[] NumDevices =
{
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"
};
```

Comment: +1 for ensuring **ALL** scenarios pass.  If a unit test fails, the unit's logic isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

In [NUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/) it would look like

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("DivideCases")]
public void DivideTest(string appNum, string hddSerial, string hddSerial)
{
    string regNumber = Registration.GenerateKey(appNum, numDevices, hddSerial);
    Assert.IsTrue(Registration.CheckKey(regNumber, appNum, out numReadDevices, hddSerial),              "Generated key does not pass check.");
    Assert.AreEqual(int.Parse(numDevices), numReadDevices,"Number of registered devices does not match requested number");
}

static object[] DivideCases =
{
    new object[] { "123", "3", "4" },
    new object[] { "12223", "35", "54" },
    new object[] { "12123123", "23", "14" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft's Unit Test Framework and make it read test data from a data source. The advantage of using MSTest is that it'll run on the Express Editions of Visual Studio.

You won't get a percentage of errors though, and I agree with @DanielMann, instead you have to ensure that your tests cover all possibilities, and that they all pass.

So, considering you have done that and now you have a list of cases to test, you can use the code below. It uses the [`DataSourceAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.aspx):

```
[TestClass]
public class RegistrationTests
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource(
        "System.Data.OleDb", 
        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\MySolution\Serial numbers.mdb""",
        "Serials",
        DataAccessMethod.Sequential
    )]
    public void GeneratingValidKeyTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        int numReadDevices;
        var appNum = TestContext.DataRow["appNum"].ToString();
        var hddSerial = TestContext.DataRow["hddSerial"].ToString();
        var numDevices = TestContext.DataRow["numDevices"].ToString();

        // Act
        var regNumber = Registration.GenerateKey(appNum, numDevices, hddSerial);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(
            Registration.CheckKey(regNumber, appNum, out numReadDevices, hddSerial), 
            "Generated key does not pass check."
        );
        Assert.AreEqual(
            int.Parse(numDevices), numReadDevices, 
            "Number of registered devices does not match requested number"
        );
    }
}
```

In the Test Explorer window you'll get an output like this (failed tests are shown first):

```
Test Name:  GeneratingValidKeyTest
Test FullName:  MySolution.UnitTest.RegistrationTests.GeneratingValidKeyTest
Test Source:    C:\MySolution\MySolution.UnitTest\RegistrationTests.cs : line 15
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00,017832

Result1 Name:   GeneratingValidKeyTest (Data Row 1)
Result1 Outcome:    Failed
Result1 Duration:   0:00:00,0082728
Result1 StackTrace: at MySolution.UnitTest.RegistrationTests.GeneratingValidKeyTest() in C:\MySolution\MySolution.UnitTest\RegistrationTests.cs:line 27
Result1 Message:    Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<11>. Actual:<12>. Number of registered devices does not match requested number

Result3 Name:   GeneratingValidKeyTest (Data Row 0)
Result3 Outcome:    Passed
Result3 Duration:   0:00:00,0089332
Result3 StackTrace:
Result3 Message:
```